# SharePoint 2013 install: Stand Alone

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm an interning student for a junior college and for my internship I must setup a test sever for SharePoint.
My questions is that I have been stuck at step 8 of the configuration wizard and am need of assistance. I have linked a screen capture of the error in question.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\`

There is an Analytics_GUID folder not being able to be shared. Try Sharing it manually. Re-run the wizard, should work

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ee9fc828-6d63-43b0-9bbc-76065182b1fd/sharepoint-2013-products-configuration-wizard-error-failed-to-create-sample-data?forum=sharepointadmin

Also, could you please share the PSDiag Log?